# ggplot2 - copying the plot to word document

Tags: r, ggplot2

I did several column plots in R studio and they look nice in the R Studio. But when I copy and paste them to my Word document they don't look nice as it seems colours are faded. Especially letters are a bit hard to read. (looks like low-resolution image)

I am wondering if there is any solution for the above problem.

Comment: While https://stackoverflow.com/q/22813723/3358272 is mostly about base plots, the same premise will apply to `ggplot2` renderings as well. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I am sorry. I couldn't workout how to increase the resolution in the way you suggested..

Comment: *Do not copy/paste.* Save (using `png()` or `ggsave()` or similar).

Comment: `ggsave()` has also a dpi option to set the resolution.