# plot labels overlap - how to expand scale of graph sheet?

Tags: r, ggplot2

## Setup/Problem:

I have created a simple scatter plot using `ggplot2` library and the `qplot()` function in RStudio.

## Issue:

The issue is that the labels overlap when I create the plot.

## Question:

1. Is there a simple way to expand the graph sheet to stop the plot labels overlapping?
2. Is there a simple way to stop the labels being cut off by the edge of the graph

I do not want to remove labels. My sense would be to expand the sheet size but I cannot seem to find a way to do that. Any help would be much appreciated.

## Research so far

1. I have investigated the `wordcloud` library as an alternative but hit the same issue.
2. I have investigated using the `scale_x_continuous(expand = c(.3, .3))` command which does allow me to expand the sheet to address the edge issue but I am looking to see if a better solution exists.
3. I have read through the `ggplot2` manual pages but have failed to find a clean solution. I felt it is time to ask for some help and a few pointers to a solution. If I find a solution I will post it.

---

## Example Output (Date File to below)

[image]

## Code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
td3 <- read.csv("td3.csv")

p <-qplot(X,Y, xaxs = "i", yaxs = "r", las = 1, data=td3, shape=as.factor(Type), label=Identifier, asp = 1)
p <- p + scale_x_continuous(expand = c(.3, .3))
p + geom_text(aes(colour=factor(Type)), angle = 30, size=4, hjust=-0.1, panel.margin = unit(50, "lines"))
```

## Test Data

```
Identifier,X,Y,,Type
1st Reference Long Title,5,280,,Super fit
2nd Reference Long Title,1,60,,fit
3rd Reference Long Title,1,60,,fit
4th Reference Long Title,3,100,,fit
5th Reference Long Title,1,14,,unfit
6th Reference Long Title,1,48,,fit
7th Reference Long Title,1,48,,fit
8th Reference Long Title,10,80,,fit
9th Reference Long Title,1,24,,unfit
10th Reference Long Title,1,80,,fit
11th Reference Long Title,1,36,,unfit
12th Reference Long Title,1,10,,unfit
13th Reference Long Title,3,60,,fit
14th Reference Long Title,3,120,,fit
15th Reference Long Title,3,80,,fit
16th Reference Long Title,10,400,,Super fit
17th Reference Long Title,5,360,,Super fit
18th Reference Long Title,2,5,,unfit
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399100/r-plot-size-and-resolution

Comment: Mr. Flick - I'll work through this on the weekend. (Traveling). Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 0):

You could either "increase the size of the canvas" before issuing the plotting command, see for example `?png` or `?jpg`.
Alternatively you could use `ggsave`, see [R plot: size and resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399100/r-plot-size-and-resolution)

G

Comment: PavoDive - I'll work through this on the weekend. (Traveling). Thank you for responding.